# How to make a website prevent mobile from sleeping

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

I'm building a web application that needs to keep track of time. The problem is that on mobile, the devices will sleep and the timer will stop. Is there a way to prevent any mobile device from sleeping using HTML, javascript, or PHP?

Comment: I'm also looking for this solution. If you find it could you please share with your solution? Thanks.